# Jackson: Serialization of primitive array leads to problematic differences compared to JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb

I found a problem when switching from a `JAXB` to a `Jackson` based serialization with the `JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule` of a simple POJO. The POJO has an integer array attribute that is handled differently between the two approaches, see the MWE below.

For the `JAXB` based approach, I basically get the result I expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<pojo dimensions="4 3"/>
```

For the `Jackson` variant the output is:

```
<POJO dimensions="4" dimensions="3"/>
```

which later fails during deserialization, as there are now two attributes with the name `dimensions`. Basically, the `Jackson` variant seems to serialize the array with the same approach for `@XmlAttribute` and `@XmlElement`, while the `JAXB` variant seems to recognize that for the use in a `@XmlAttribute` it is not necessary to repeat the attribute name and simply concat the values separated by a space delimiter.

Is there any way to get the `Jackson`-based variant to behave the same as the `JAXB` one?

---

## MWE

### `POJO.java`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

public class POJO{
    
    @XmlAttribute
    private int[] dimensions;

    public POJO() {}

    public POJO(
            int[] dimensions
    ) {
        this.dimensions = dimensions;
    }

    public void setDimensions(int[] v){this.dimensions = v;}
    public int[] getDimensions(){return dimensions;}

}
```

### `Main.java`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jakarta.xmlbind.JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {
        
        POJO pojo = new POJO(new int[]{4,3});
        
        jaxb(pojo);
        jackson(pojo);
        
    }
    
    public static void jaxb(POJO pojo) throws JAXBException{
        
        System.out.println("JAXB");
        
        // Serialize
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(pojo.getClass());

        //Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            
        // Creating the Document object
        StringWriter document = new StringWriter();

        // Marshaling the User object into a Document object
        marshaller.marshal(pojo, document);

        //
        String serialized = document.toString();
        
        System.out.println("serialized:");
        System.out.println(serialized);
        
        // Deserialize
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(serialized.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        POJO result = (POJO)unmarshaller.unmarshal(stream);
        
        assert (result != null);
    }
    
    public static void jackson(POJO pojo) throws JsonProcessingException{
        
        System.out.println("Jackson");
        
        // Serialize
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = XmlMapper.builder()
                .defaultUseWrapper(false)
                .addModule(new JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule())
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
                .build();
        String serialized = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pojo);
        
        System.out.println("serialized:");
        System.out.println(serialized);
        
        // Deserialize
        XmlMapper objectMapper2 = new XmlMapper();
        objectMapper2.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);
        objectMapper2.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        objectMapper2.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper2.registerModule(new JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule());      
        
        POJO result = (POJO)objectMapper.readValue(serialized,POJO.class);
        
        assert (result != null);
        
    }
}
```

### `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.mr</groupId>
    <artifactId>qarrayserializationjackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- Jackson   -->
        <!--<jackson.core.databind.version>2.12.3</jackson.core.databind.version>-->
        <jackson.dataformat.protobuf.version>2.15.2</jackson.dataformat.protobuf.version>
        <jackson.dataformat.xml.version>2.15.2</jackson.dataformat.xml.version>
        <jackson.dataformat.yaml.version>2.15.2</jackson.dataformat.yaml.version>
        <!-- JAXB -->
        <jakarta.xml.bind.jaxb-api.version>4.0.0</jakarta.xml.bind.jaxb-api.version>
        <org.glassfish.jaxb.jaxb-runtime.version>4.0.3</org.glassfish.jaxb.jaxb-runtime.version>
    </properties>
    
    <!-- DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependencies>
        <!--           -->
        <!-- 3rd party -->
        <!--           -->
        <!-- Jakarta -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.xml.bind.jaxb-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${org.glassfish.jaxb.jaxb-runtime.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.dataformat.protobuf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.dataformat.xml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.dataformat.xml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.dataformat.yaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--           -->
        <!-- Testing   -->
        <!--           -->
        <!-- Own       -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

## Serialization output

see above

## Logs

### `Jackson` error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Duplicate attribute 'dimensions'.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,37]
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._initializeXmlReader(XmlFactory.java:734)
```